# How can I change text of tabs on product review page magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How can I change the text of tabs on the product description page?

As currently, I am having their name as **details**. So I want to change it as **highlights**.

file path where and how can I change it?

**EDIT**  Code of Ultimo Catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 

<!-- 
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
--> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
<body> 
<referenceContainer name="content" > 
<!-- <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/topattributes.phtml" name="product.info.topattribute" after="product.info.media"> 
</block>  -->
<block class="Infortis\Base\Block\Product\View" name="product-view-wrapper" template="product/view.phtml" before="-"> </block> 
<container name="container_product_image_1" label="Product View, Image Column" /> 
<container name="container_product_primary_1" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_primary_2" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 2" /> 
<container name="container_product_secondary_1" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_secondary_2" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 2" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_primary_1" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_primary_2" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 2" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_secondary_1" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_secondary_2" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 2" /> 
<!-- Static blocks --> 



<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_product_secondary_bottom"> 
<arguments> 
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_secondary_bottom</argument> 
</arguments> 
</block> 
</referenceContainer> 
<!-- Reset attributes of main containers --> 
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main" htmlTag="" htmlClass="" before="-" /> 
<referenceContainer name="product.info.media" htmlTag="" htmlClass="" after="product.info.main" /> 
<!-- Insert product view blocks into the new product view wrapper --> 
<move element="product.info.main" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.media" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="bundle.options.container" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.details" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.upsell" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 

<!-- Move some blocks to new positions --> 
<!-- <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final" /> --> 
<!-- <move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.main" after="-" /> --> 
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price" /> 
<move element="container_product_primary_1" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title" /> 
<move element="container_product_primary_2" destination="product.info.main" after="-" /> 
<!-- Move some blocks outside the "product.info.main" to manipulate their position inside template file --> 
<move element="product.info.weight" destination="product-view-wrapper" before="product.info.review" />
<move element="page.main.title" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.review" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<!-- Product collateral data (tabs) --> 
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details" template="Infortis_Base::product/view/details.phtml" > <arguments> 
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Kit Components</argument> 
<argument name="show_tabs" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::showTabs" /> 
</arguments> 
<!-- Custom static blocks as tabs --> 
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_cms_block1" group="detailed_info"> 
<arguments> 
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_tab1</argument> 
<argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getStaticBlockTitle"> 
<param name="id">block_product_tab1</param> 
</argument> 
</arguments> 
</block> 
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_cms_block2" group="detailed_info"> 
<arguments> 
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_tab2</argument> 
<argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getStaticBlockTitle"> 
<param name="id">block_product_tab2</param> 
</argument> 
</arguments> 
</block> 
</referenceBlock> 
<referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related" > 
<action method="setTemplate"> 
<argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getRelatedProductsTemplate" /> 
</action> 
</referenceBlock> 
<referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell" hide="true"> 
<action method="setTemplate"> 
<argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getUpsellProductsTemplate" /> 
<!-- TODO: --> 
<argument name="is_responsive" xsi:type="string">false</argument> 
<argument name="show_items" xsi:type="string">3</argument> 
</action> 
</referenceBlock> 
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.crosssell" hide="true"> 
<action method="setTemplate"> 
<argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Infortis_Base::product/list/slider.phtml</argument> 
</action> 
</referenceBlock> 
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/topattributes.phtml" name="product.info.topattribute"  after="product.info.main"/>      
</referenceContainer>
<move element="reviews.tab" destination="main.content" after="-"/>
</body> 
</page>
```

Comment: Did you get the solution

Comment: @ManojDeswal  as ultiomo already overide it . So unable to change in override . But In vendor its changing . code of ultimo catalog_product_view.xml I have posted .

Comment: wait let me see , I hope I have answer for this and that would work for you

Comment: try solution , and let me know if any problem ....  no need to extend anything ... just add the given code and it should work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open your ULTIMO `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
/app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

And **add this code in the end of you XML file before body tag**

After this `<move element="reviews.tab" destination="main.content" after="-"/>`

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
    <action method="setTitle">
        <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Highlights</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

**Keep Cache disabled**  or **flush your cache**

Comment: can you help with this please ?  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199967/show-description-of-product-in-wish-list-phtml-file

Answer (score 4):

Inside

> Magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

**Note:** ***Override*** this XML file in your Theme directory.

> app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

**1st Way**

Find Below code to change the **title**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</block>
```

Add above code inside `<referenceContainer name="content">` and change the title. It will fix your issue.

**2nd way:** add below code inside `catalog_product_view.xml` file

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
    <action method="setTitle">
        <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Highlights</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: I need to change just last argument ?  mean last line ?

Comment: yes, `<argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">highlights</argument>`

Comment: I am using a theme ultimo , And there is already a file with same name .And there is no code like this .  So how to override this now ? As I change in vendor and it worked for me .

Comment: can you please add the code of `catalog_product_view.xml` file of Ultimo theme? So that i can show you where to add it. Also please check my updated answer

Comment: As I  tried in code to change strings as well so you can see in code . Updated code kindly check

Comment: Add above the XML code (in my answer) inside `<referenceContainer name="content">` and change the title. It will fix your issue

Comment: <referenceContainer name="content">  is in start . So I have to paste in start of file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66344/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-learner).

Answer (score 3):

Abhishek's code is working fine. If you want add more tab use below code and this in

> app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="Yourcustom.tab" template="product/view/Yourcustom.phtml" group="detailed_info">
    <arguments>                                              
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your custom tab name here</argument>  
    </arguments>
</block>
```