# Show description of product in wish list phtml file

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, frontend, wishlist

I want to get **description** of **product** in **wishlist** Page, I tried this code In **`list.phtml`** file but no luck .

```
<?php echo $_product->getDescription() ?>
```

**EDIT**

my code now look like this

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product_id=$this->getItem()->getProduct()->getId();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
?>
<strong class="product-item-description">
    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($product->getDescription()) ?>
</strong>
```

Comment: Where do you want to show the product description exactly?

Comment: @DineshYadav  actually  wherever wishlist appear with it, product description of this product  aswell should occur

Comment: you have any idea @DineshYadav ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Display description in wishlist you have to follow below steps-

**Create a new file `description.phtml` at location**

> vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/item/column/description.phtml

**In description.phtml add below code**

```
<?php 
$item = $block->getItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();
?>
<strong class="product-item-description">
    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($product->getDescription()) ?>
</strong>
```

**Now at path**

> vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/layout/wishlist_index_index.xml

in this file add below code after `customer.wishlist.item.name` block

```
<block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info" name="customer.wishlist.item.description" template="item/column/description.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

**Note:- Do not change in core files, add in your theme directory**

**EDIT :** proper way to load data

**Create a new block file in your custom module at path**

> app/code/Namespace/Module/Block

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

class Description extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info
{

  protected $_productloader;  


  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader

    ) {


        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getDescription()
    {
        $id = $this->getItem()->getProduct()->getId();
        $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
        return $product->getDescription();
    }

}
```

In layout file replace block class from `Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info` to `Namespace\Module\Block\Description`

After that in your template file you can get product description using below code

```
$block->getDescription();
```

To create a custom module you can follow this [article](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/)

Comment: class is showing now in console but no data is showing

Comment: <strong class="product-item-description">
    </strong>      just this is showing in console

Comment: In the wishlist product object there is no description, so you may need to create a new block file and load product there

Comment: can you give clue or some help maybe  about ir?

Comment: Create a custom block and load product in it, then you can get product description in template file,  check this answer to load product https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/94853

Comment: he is using static id , like 1 and 20 in example. in my case from where I will get id ?

Comment: Try `$this->getItem()->getProduct()->getId()` in block for product id

Comment: kindly check my edit , my code  now look like that still not

Comment: Sorry I run after decompile now working :D . by adding in template :p

Comment: It will be working but it is not a good practice to load product in template, you should use block or helper file to load data

Comment: I am almost done in solution bro kindly  if possible guide me  for helper file or block ?

Comment: In my case it is giving me an error like this `Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Custom\CustomerWishlist\Block\Customlist::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory, instance of Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test\var\generation\Custom\CustomerWishlist\Block\Customlist\Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in `