# Magento 2 - How to display description product listing page of wishlist?

Tags: magento-2.1, wishlist

I want to display description on the product listing page of Wishlist.

Facing the Fatal error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Satish\Wishlist\Block\Description' not found in /home/decure/public_html/test/var/generation/SatishWishlist/Block/Description/Interceptor.php on line 7

`description.php` file in block

```
<?php

namespace Satish\Wishlist\Block;

class Description extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info
{
    protected $_productloader;  

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader
    ) {
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        $id = $this->getItem()->getProduct()->getId();
        $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
        return $product->getDescription();
    }
}
```

Comment: please share `Satish\Wishlist\Block\Description` file and have you run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command?

Comment: Satish\Wishlist\Block\Description
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context; File:
/home/decure/public_html/test/app/code/Satish/Wishlist/block/description.php

Comment: @kunj I edited question with description.php block file

Comment: I have added answer hope it will help.

Comment: If that answer helped you then please accept it so it will help to others.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
namespace Satish\Wishlist\Block;
class Description extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info{
    protected $_productloader;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader
    ) {
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context,$httpContext);
    }
    public function getDescription()
    {
        $id = $this->getItem()->getProduct()->getId();
        $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
        return $product->getDescription();
    }
}
?>
```

Actually, your last parent block is `Magento\Wishlist\Block\AbstractBlock`

below is it's construct method.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }
```

your XML code should be like this:

```
        <referenceContainer name="customer.wishlist.items">
       <block class="Satish\Wishlist\Block\Description" name="customer.wishlist.item.description" template="Satish_Wishlist::item/column/description.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

And in that `description.phtml` the code should be as below.

```
<strong class="product-item-description">
    <?php echo $block->getDescription() ?>
</strong>
```

Comment: Same Fatal Error . I am not used the second construct method. after replace the description php file  code. now no Compilation error .

Comment: @ssatish4u, yes, you just need to put my updated code which is done in your, after that you will need to run`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: i have already compile after placing your code in description block file. I am not used the construct method where i do this the second one. now there no compilation error.

Comment: You do not need to put second That is only for information.  This class  `\Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info` extends 
this  class `\Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column` and finally we have `\Magento\Wishlist\Block\AbstractBlock` class who has `__construct` with `public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);}`

Comment: Yes thank you but error was solved of compilation. now the page is blank https://test.decure.in/wishlist/

Comment: @ssatish4u, have you corrected this from `$this->_productloader->create()->load($id);        return $product->getDescription(); `  To   `$product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);        return $product->getDescription();`

Comment: Done changes https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199967/show-description-of-product-in-wish-list-phtml-file I've used this url to achieve this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81506/discussion-between-ssatish4u-and-kunj).

Comment: wishlist product listing coming without decription - without error

Comment: @ssatish4u I have updated my answer please review it. We must continue in chat

Comment: i don't why its not reflecting my side. :(

Comment: https://we.tl/uudr8zKiwl  download the module